# Databricks + H2O PySparkling: addURL Py4JException

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, h2o, sparkling-water

I am a newbie to H2O and spark framework and I am having troubles with on boarding `H2O+Spark (sparkling-water)` PySparkling in Databricks. I have a 12 worker cluster running in Databricks in 1.5.2 environment.

Steps I took were as following: 
1. Attach (Installed) necessary libraries (six, requests, tabulate, and future) required by [H2O](http://www.h2o.ai/download/sparkling-water/spark15) to my cluster

2. Then, I took the necessary .egg file from `sparkling-water-1.5.14/py/dist` folder after unzipping it from the sparkling-water-1.5.14.zip package.
3. I also attached the `sparkling-water-assembly-1.5.14.jar` to my Databricks cluster
4. I am able to `import h2o` successfully. however, when I run the following cell in my python NB in Databricks, I am getting exception below:

   Initiate H2OContext on top of Spark
   `from pysparkling import * 
   hc = H2OContext(sc).start()
   import h2o`

I am getting following error

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method addURL([class java.net.URL]) does not exist
```

Sincerely appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug in PySparkling](http://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/SW-137). [A fix](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/commit/7f5fef09cfc6b746f743198e438ec4eb2ab09403) has been already committed but is still waiting for the next release, might be introduced in 1.5.15.

You can try building Sparkling Water from that branch yourself and use that before we release the next version.